# Add post classes for custom taxonomies to custom post type?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I was surprised to learn that custom taxonomies aren't added as body or post classes like categories and tags are.

I'm sure this will be added in a future version of WordPress, but in the meantime I need to add a custom taxonomy to the post class so that I can style post in a certain category in that taxonomy differently.

It'd be most elegant to filter the post class and add the taxonomies to it. [I found a snippet](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-hack-automatically-add-post-name-to-the-body-class%29;) to pull off a similar trick with the body class, but I haven't been successful in adapting it:

```
function wpprogrammer_post_name_in_body_class( $classes ){
 if( is_singular() )
 {
  global $post;
  array_push( $classes, "{$post->post_type}-{$post->post_name}" );
 }
 return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpprogrammer_post_name_in_body_class' );
```

A bit more crudely, I thought about using the_terms function to create my own classes for the custom posts, something like this:

```
<div class="<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy', '', ' ', '' ); ?>"></div>
```

But then I'd have to filter out the HTML that `the_term` generates.

Am I missing anything obvious here, is there a simpler way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a snippet of code [courtesy of mfields](http://www.wptavern.com/forum/troubleshooting/1758-custom-taxonomy-css-class.html#post17182) that solved this problem for me, here's what I ended up using:

```
<?php   // Add custom taxonomies to the post class

    add_filter( 'post_class', 'custom_taxonomy_post_class', 10, 3 );

    if( !function_exists( 'custom_taxonomy_post_class' ) ) {

        function custom_taxonomy_post_class( $classes, $class, $ID ) {

            $taxonomy = 'listing-category';

            $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomy );

            if( !empty( $terms ) ) {

                foreach( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {

                    if( !in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {

                        $classes[] = $term->slug;

                    }

                }

            }

            return $classes;

        }

    }  ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** As of [WordPress 4.2-alpha-31271](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/04216633b2fc6e21a458481af3bd0abf036e59a3) (23 January 2015), CSS classes for custom taxonomy terms are now automatically added by WordPress core when using `get_post_class()`.

The following code snippet is no longer necessary.

---

Here's a good utility function that will **add *all registered, public taxonomy terms*** to the [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) for use as CSS hooks in themes:

```
/**
* Add Custom Taxonomy Terms To The Post Class
*/

add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse_2266_custom_taxonomy_post_class', 10, 3 );

if ( ! function_exists('wpse_2266_custom_taxonomy_post_class') ) {
    function wpse_2266_custom_taxonomy_post_class($classes, $class, $ID) {

        $taxonomies_args = array(
            'public' => true,
            '_builtin' => false,
        );

        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $taxonomies_args, 'names', 'and' );

        $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, (array) $taxonomies );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {
                if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {
                    $classes[] = $term->slug;
                }
            }
        }

        $classes[] = 'clearfix';

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

*Inspiration and credit from Jan Fabry's previous answer.*

Put the above code in your theme's `functions.php` file. Then, whenever the `post_class()` is used in a template:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

It will output any public custom taxonomy term(s) attached to the post, in addition to all of the default post classes. For example:

```
<article id="post-247" class="post-247 post-type ... status-publish hentry clearfix">
```

It handily works with Custom Post Types and Taxonomies.

Answer (score 3):

I have an improvement on @rjb's answer (I don't have enough reputation to comment, sorry).  I was getting an "array to strings conversion" error with debug mode turned on, so I did a foreach loop of the returned taxonomies and now there's no error.

Hope this helps someone!

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'custom_taxonomy_post_class', 10, 3 );

function custom_taxonomy_post_class($classes, $class, $ID) {

    $taxonomies_args = array(
        'public' => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
    );

    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $taxonomies_args, 'names', 'and' );

    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomy );

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {
                $classes[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }
    }


}

    $classes[] = 'clearfix';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: This version should definitely be used instead of rjb's answer! Thank you bhammie85!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms), you could use [`get_the_terms`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/category-template.php#L898), which will return the taxonomy term *objects*. The Codex has documentation for the tag-only version, [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags).

That would give you something like this:

```
function wpprogrammer_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_singular() )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'my_custom_taxonomy');
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = 'custom_tag_' . $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpprogrammer_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for pointing me in the right direction! I hand't tried get_the_terms or get_the_tags, get_the_tags didn't quite work for me, but I did find a solution with get_the_terms that worked.

Comment: @JLeuze: Indeed, my code was incorrect, it had `get_the_tags` where it needed to be `get_the_terms`, the more generic version - I'll correct it. But the Codex only explains `get_the_tags`, that's why I included it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some coding and I add support of post class, to my plugin called: **Custom post types and taxonomies manager**

In new taxonomy form is option called Post class. Which allows to add **category|tag-{slug}** and **{slug}-{tax_value_slug}** to the post class.

Download  here
https://github.com/Pravdomil/wp-custom-post-types-man/archive/master.zip